# Automatically set Identity column value same as another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named `CurrentMachine` and 10 columns.  I currently have the column `[MachineId]` as primary `identity(1,1)`.  I want to instead change the `[MachineID]` column to be the same value as the `[MachineName]` column automatically instead of adding increments of 1 for the ID.

Can this be done?  Hope I'm making sense here...

Comment: Have you considered a computed column?

Comment: You can alter the table to make the [MachineName] the Primary Key and drop the MachineId column or make it a computed column as per @RichBenner. Note this will only work if MachineName is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to do this? In general you don't want to eliminate primary keys!  When you do you want to make sure you replace with an acceptable key.  Will MachineName always be unique?  You can add a unique constraint to MachineName if you are worried about getting duplicates.....  Please expand on what you are trying to accomplish overall (the reason) and we willl better be able to help guide you.  Otherwise technically you can drop key, alter the column and make it a calculated column but it is not something I would normally advise.

Comment: If you must, you can add an insert/update trigger on your CurrentMachine table